# Is the use of that necessary

Tags: usage

In the following sentence, is the use of **that** necessary

> I told her when she came to Delhi, I would show her all historical monuments.

I think with **that** and **without that** the sentence is correct both ways

Answer (score -1):

`I told her when she came to Delhi, I would show her all historical monuments.`

In the sentence above *that* is optional and does not make any change in meaning even if we  use it. It is a conjunction and it is implied even if we do not use it

I think *that* is omitted especially in speech.

`I told her that punishment was not enough`

In the sentence given above *that* is not optional because it is a determiner. If we remove *that* meaning changes.